# Short story where a snail-like alien creature preys upon the protagonist in the end

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

The description of the story may be a little bit wrong since I read this story many years ago. Also, the short story is not recent (thinking maybe written in the 50s or 60s) and it is science fiction/horror.

It deals with this man who is going to buy a relic from a seller and the seller tells this story about alien creatures which don't have any other senses besides the touch, they behave just like snails and are really slow. The thing is the aliens use objects to prey. When other creatures touch these objects they enter a trance-like state and become hypnotized so they are unable to move to the advantage of the aliens which have the time to hunt them. As the seller tells this, he deposits the relic in the man's hands and he becomes instantly unable to move. The story ends with an alien snail-like monster entering the room and slowly going in the protagonist's direction.

I have read other threads with similar questions, however, this is not *On The Fourth Planet*.

Comment: This is a really nice description and I think you have covered all of the main points! If you remember anything else do not hesitate to [edit] your question. You might also consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: Sounds like "The Hypnoglyph" by John Ciardi, described in [this Q & A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161871/tactile-traps-and-cannibal-matriarchy/). Is that it?

Comment: You can read "The Hypnoglyph" here: https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n01_1953-07/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v005n01_1953-07#page/n25/mode/2up

Comment: That's it! That's "The Hypnoglyph". Thank you so much user14111!

Comment: @David You're welcome!