# Short story anthology, one story was about a warship being prepared and sent on a bombing run

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I recall that, as a child, I purchased a science fiction anthology of short stories in British Home Stores (BHS) sometime in the mid 1980s. It had a reddish-orange cover with white writing and drawn pictures of aliens, space ships, etc. and I suspect it may have been specially made for BHS as well.  It was about an inch or so thick and must have contained 20-25 stories from various authors.

I never got around to reading most of the stories but one I recall reading was about a ship automatically being prepped and armed, taking off and bombing an enemy city. The conclusion was that all the people had been wiped out and the systems kept the war going automatically because there was nobody left to turn the machinery off.

I've been thinking about that book recently and resolved to find it (or the stories at least) and get around to finally reading it.

Comment: One of the _There Will Be War_ series of anthologies?  A couple of them had red-orange covers, and your story is one that could have been in one.  https://www.librarything.com/series/There+Will+Be+War

Comment: No, the colouring you mention is about right but this was an A5 sized hardback book with no author or editor names on the cover (that I recall).

Comment: Somewhat similar to [_Down the Bright Way_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2900) but it is a novel. See the description at (**warning**) the TVTropes page for [Absurdly Dedicated Worker](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AbsurdlyDedicatedWorker).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The story you mention is [Flying Dutchman](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74284) by Ward Moore.  This [anthology](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?29172) matches the color scheme you describe.

[image]

The book was previously identified here: [Anthology book with story about robotic bombers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95038/58193), h/t to [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot).

Comment: Asked and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95038/58193) with some more detail.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thanks. Will see if we get an acceptance.

Comment: This is it :O  Thanks for finding this for me! :D

Comment: @TheBetpet you are most welcome, and welcome to scfi stack exchange!